# About javascript function structure

Tags: javascript

I want to call below function(focusOnfn.focusOn()), by a specific id.Like we are calling in jquery `$("#selectorId").function();`

```
   var focusOnfn = function(){
        value: $(this).val(),
        focusOn: function(){
            alert($(this).val())
        }
    }
```

see this example http://jsfiddle.net/gopalan100/ZSwe8/8/

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to ask? I can't parse your question.

Comment: So you want to be able to do `focusOnfn('selector').focusOn()`? It's not clear to be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey there, @raj! Your question, as it stands, is unclear. Could you please go back and revise the phrasing so it's clearer what you're trying to achieve? We'll be more able to assist you then.

Comment: I believe he means something like `document.querySelectorAll("#selectorId")`

Comment: I think he want to write code in pure javascript, and he would like to call functions by putting dot on dom objects, like jQuery do. E.g. `document.getElementById('mydiv').focusOn();`

Comment: @SajithNair: Yes, You got my question.

Comment: see this structure,var focusBlurFn = {
        textvalue: document.getElementById("search"),
        focusOn: function(){
            alert(this.textvalue.value)
        }
}

focusBlurFn.focusOn(); but i want to pass textvalue id as $("#sdf") and i will get in "this" inside function.

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of this writing, your question is a bit vague.

I believe you are asking how to query by CSS selectors without using jQuery.
If that's the case, you can use the `querySelectorAll` function of the `document` object:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#myId"); //simple ID selector, use .getElementById instead
document.querySelectorAll("p.linksAreSpoilers a:hover"); // good use case, when selecting from a complex source
```

This is possible only in modern browsers, because it was added to the specification recently.

If you want the cross-browser version, you could take a look at [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), jQuery's core selector library.

And if you want to create a library which supports jQuery-esque syntax, you can use inheritance, as demonstrated in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h6KzL/1/

```
//Create a constructor, this is just a function that returns nothing and sets its own properties (this.<SOMETHING>)
function ElementObject(query) {
    this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(query);
}
//Add functions to the constructor's prototype
ElementObject.prototype.getFirst = function () {
    return this.elements[0];
}

//Create our "public" function, ideally all code above would be private (e.g. inside a module or something similar
function $(query) {
    return new ElementObject(query);
}

alert($("#myDiv").getFirst());
```

Note that using $ for your library's function is a bad idea, because lots of people alredy use $ for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd like to do something like this

```
 $("#selectorId").on('focusOn', function(){
        value: $(this).val(),
        focusOn: function(){
            alert($(this).val())
        }
    }
$("#selectorId").trigger('focusOn');
```

"*Javascript way*":

```
var myEl = document.querySelector("#selectorId");
myEl.addEventListener("focusOn", function(e) {
    // what ever here
});
// Trigger
myEl.dispatchEvent(focusOn);
```

Comment: yes i100, but in javascript way.

Comment: rai, your example is with jquery...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
Object.prototype.focusOnfn = function() {
    return {
        value: this.value,
        focusOn: function(){
            alert(this.value);
        }
    }
}
```